# Find next post item in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to make my selenium to find next post item in a WordPress category. i want web driver find the post, Click it, Opens it and copy some text in the post, Then it Click Go Back and click on the post after that in the same category. this should be in a loop.
i don't know how to make it to go back and find the next post.

the code is :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('example.com/category')


scpara = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]/div[1]').click()
```

the LI xpath is li[1], After that it's , li[2] and it goes on

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]/div[1]
```

this is the next post xpath

Comment: Can you post your current code please

Comment: @0m3r Done, can you please help me?

Comment: @JeremyHunt : You need to share your html or url and your expected output on your original post?